# Float image on top of entire webpage?

Tags: css-float, floating

is there a way in CSS to float images on top of your entire document without disrupting the html?

similar to when you click the cornify button [here](http://www.cornify.com/) but without the button.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
.myclass {
    position: fixed;
}
```

You can read about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).